# Ejecucion de comados cmd en java que requieren privilegios de administrador

Tags: java, windows, cmd

Estoy intentando hacer que un programa en java ejecute algunos comandos de subsistemas de red de Windows.

Utilizo el siguiente método para inicializar y ejecutar los comandos:

```
public CommandObjectOutput CMD_INOUT(String[]Comando) throws IOException{
boolean err = false;
        CommandObjectOutput out;
        Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
        Process proc = rt.exec(Comando);

        BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

        BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
             InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

        // Lectura de la salida del commando.
        String s = null, outT = "", outE="";
        while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
            outT = outT + "\n" + s;
        }
        outT = outT + "\n";
        
        /* Lectura de possibles errores del comando.*/
        while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(s);
            outE= outE + "\n" + s; 
            err=true;
        }
        outE = outE + "\n";
        
        out = new CommandObjectOutput(err,outT,outE);
        return out;
    }
```

El método CMD_INOUT es relativamente sencillo y devuelve los resultados que contiene con un boolean si existe algún error.
El problema viene cuando tengo que ejecutar uno de estos 5 comandos:

> ipconfig /renew

> netsh int ip reset

> netsh int tcp set global autotuninglevel=disabled

> netsh int tcp set global rss=enabled

En su forma mas benigna solo me devuelve un error diciendo que esa instrucción requiere de privilegios.
He probado a ponerlos como .bat y/o en .exe para forzar a que se ejecuten como administrador.
Pero en el mejor de estos casos ignora la instrucción y en el peor bloque la ejecución global del programa.
¿Alguien sabe como ejecutar estos comandos desde el método de arriba como administrador?

Comment: No puedes solo ejecutar unas líneas como administrador. Si o sí tienes que pedir elevación al usuario. Lo que se suele hacer es iniciar brevemente un proceso con permisos de administrador que haga lo indispensable y termine.

Comment: De hecho esa fue mi primera solución pero queda feísimo ya que pide la clave de administrador a través de una consola CMD, Además no funciona si el usuario Administrator no esta habilitado. ¿No sabrás como hacer que salte el cartel de privilegios de Windows que siempre salta cuando se intenta ejecutar algo con privilegios?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Una solución valida es usar una herramienta previa que permita la elevación de los comandos a elevar.
Como por ejemplo elevate.exe que tiene una licencia de uso del MIT.
Simplemente se ponen los comados dentro de un script bat y se le llama a elevate.exe junto al script.
Llamándolo de la forma:

```
src\\main\\java\\Main\\elevate.exe script.bat
```

Esto hace saltar una solitud de escalada de privilegios de Windows, en vez de solicitar la contraseña de administrador por consola y funciona con cualquier usuario.

Por lo que he visto hay otras herramientas que hacen mas o menos lo mismo pero el asunto de las licencias es complicado.

Comment: Cabe decir que \\ es porque lo estoy llamando desde otro sistema.